# How to differentiate between "normal textview" or "underline textview" or "textview with link" via accessibility in android

Tags: android, accessibility

In my application i have a textview with text as underline and also have another normal textview like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="showPrivacyPolicy"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy_underline"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pp_no_underline"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="showPrivacyPolicy"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy_no_underline"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And using below strings from strings.xml

```
<string name="privacy_policy_underline"><u>Privacy Policy</u></string>

<string name="privacy_policy_no_underline">Privacy Policy</string>
```

When user click on any one of above it shows **Terms and conditions text**. Now when user makes accessibility ON and select any one of above text, system spell both textviews with same pronunciation. **Here accessibility pronounce  underline text and normal text as same. How user can differentiate between underline text and normal text**

Comment: Why does it matter? It looks like they both do the same thing.

Comment: As per https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en QA team expecting that "As the hyperlinked area of text within that item is spoken, listen for a chime to indicate hyperlinked text."

Comment: But they're both clickable links.

Comment: Here mainly i want to know how the user can deduct the textview is "underline text" or it is a link or normal textview.? there should a difference so that user can know that it is a link

Comment: Underlining something doesn't make it a link. Giving it a URL makes it a link. If you want some clickable text that takes you somewhere else in the app, then you should be using a Button.

Comment: In my application "Privacy policy" is a underline text and when user click on that it shows the another screen which has "Privacy policy" details....

Comment: Yes, but if the details are also part of the app, you should be using a Button, not clickable text.

Comment: As per HID i should use only the underline textview. One more things why i am not using as hyper link is because of hyper link shows the text colour as blue,  But as per my HID the textview should be having underline and it text colour is not blue. So i am using textview with underline to implement this..

Comment: So then why do you have both an underlined and non-underlined TextView?

Comment: Just to explain the issue in better way i have used both textviews. Actually in my app only one textview with underline will be there. And as it is underline textview QA is expecting to know the user as underline text not as simple textview..

Comment: But neither one is a simple TextView. They're both clickable and perform the same action. Why differentiate if they do the same exact thing?

Comment: Please note that i have only one textview with underline and when user tap on that user should know that it is the link, it should not treat like simple textview.

They are raising this issue by reading  
  support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en